# How to clone the datepicker text field?

Tags: jquery, clone

Hi could anyone please explain me about,How to clone the datepicker text field for follwing code.The following will be the jsp.

```
 $("#workexperience").click(function() {
        var jobfromdate = 0;
        var remve = '<td><button type="button"  class="removeworkexperience" class="btn btn-info" >x</button></td>';
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr').prev('tr')).find('td:last-child').remove();
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').append(remve);
        $('input[id^="jobfromdate"]').each(function() {

            $(this).attr('id', this.id + jobfromdate);
            $('#jobfromdate' + jobfromdate).datepicker();
            jobfromdate++;
            alert(1);
        });
```

**JSp**

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <input type="text" id="previouscompanyname" name="previouscompanyname" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " value="${param.previouscompanyname}"/>          
        <p id="previouscompanyname" style="color: red"/>
        <html:errors property="previouscompanyname"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input type="text" id="jobtitle" name="jobtitle" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " value="${param.jobtitle}"/>          
        <p id="jobtitle" style="color: red"/>
        <html:errors property="jobtitle"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input type="text"  class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="jobfromdate" name="jobfromdate"  value="${param.dateofjoining}"/>
        <html:errors property="jobfromdate"/>    </td>
    <td>  
        <input type="text"  class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="jobtodate" name="jobtodate"  value="${param.dateofjoining}"/>
        <html:errors property="jobtodate"/>
    </td>
    <td>     
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="workexperience">Add New</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you share the html sample as well

Comment: it should be as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8FHdh/1/ - but it will be better if you can assign a class to the datepicker input so that we can lookup it via the class selector - the id of an element must be unique

Comment: I have shred my html could u please see.]

Comment: A **[clone example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ydch/1/)**

Comment: The above link in not opening

Comment: could anyone please help me for this